# What's a good User-Agent parsing plugin for django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, cross-platform, user-agent

Is there a User-Agent-String parsing plugin or middleware that you can recommend. Right now  I am using [django-smartagent](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smartagent/0.1.1), but its dictionary is not complete and not updated very often.

Comment: What do you want with user-agent strings?

Comment: @Chris: To determine the type of device and fetch the appropriate template for that device

Answer (score 2):

The browscap files can be read by the pythong ConfigParser library and are updated regularly.

http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp

This is a module that shows using ConfigParser to read, from a older djangosnippet posting (267) slightly modified version to allow for easier 'finding' of the browscap.ini file

http://pastebin.com/viD5F7nV

Then in middleware

```
BCAP=browsecap.BrowserCapabilitues()

class UAMiddleware:
    def process_request(self,request):
        request.browser=BCAP(request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT',''))
```

and in view..

```
if request.browser.is_mobile():
    ...
```