# Is there a bulletproof way of telling whether a device is a phone, a tablet, or a computer?

Tags: django, user-interface, cross-platform, compatibility, device

This question is related to: [What's a good User-Agent parsing plugin for django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272523/whats-a-good-user-agent-parsing-plugin-for-django)

I have three layout styles: one for PC browsers, one for tablets, and one for mobiles.

The [smartagent](https://github.com/jamespacileo/django-smartagent) plugin can tell me whether the device is a mobile device, but there are several issues:

- Some tablets show up as a mobile device (Galaxy Tab) and some don't (iPad, Playbook)
- If something is not a mobile device, how can I be sure its a PC versus a tablet?

Are there any sure ways of finding out what is the device type?

Thanks

Comment: Ask the user.  In other words, show the user the various layouts, and let him or her pick one.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in checking out foundation.zurb.com

It will allow you to adapt the styling according to the device width, with preset style for phones, tablets, and desktops.

Edit: Bootstrap 2.0 now also allows for responsive design http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/